# Roles mapping between Scrum and XP methodologies

Tags: scrum, methodology, extreme-programming

A lot of people mix Scrum and XP methodologies. But these methodologies have different set of roles. I tried to make mapping between them. This is result:

```
 ________________________________
|    Scrum roles    |  XP roles  |
|___________________|____________|
| Development Team  | Programmer |
|                   |   Tester   |
|___________________|____________|
|   Product Owner   |  Customer  |
|___________________|____________|
|    Scrum Master   |   Coach    |
|                   |  Tracker   |
|___________________|____________|
|        N/A        | Consultant |
|___________________|____________|
|        N/A        |  Big Boss  |
|___________________|____________|
```

Is this correct? I have big doubts about this.

**Update**

---

A little explanation of my question. The question is, to which roles in Scrum I should delegate authority of XP roles.

In case of the Development Team it's easy. All teams already have Programmers and Testers.

For Product Owner it's easy too. Product Owner speaks on behalf of the Customer. So, Product Owner in Scrum is the same that Customer in XP.

Delegate authority of Coach is harder. Should it be Scrum Master, because he controls compliance the methodology. Or Scrum Master responsible only for Scrum, and XP Coach should be another person.

The same problem with Tracker. Who should be the conscience of team? Scrum Master or it's better to appoint this to another person?

Comment: Most people who mix both use the practices from XP with the process from Scrum. So you'd use the Scrum roles.

Comment: @AndrewClear It's exactly my case. I made some explanation in my question. Sorry, if it was not very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Delegate authority of Coach is harder. Should it be Scrum Master,
>   because he controls compliance the methodology. Or Scrum Master
>   responsible only for Scrum, and XP Coach should be another person.

Unfortunately best answer for above part would be: **it depends**.
You need to take into accounts couple aspects of your question:

## Scrum and XP operate on different levels

XP defines very rigorously set of engineering practices that have to be used by the team and process around them.

On the other hand **Scrum treats engineering practices** and exact way the team does the work as **black box**.

## Who is your Scrum Master

Scrum Master as defined by [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guide) is management role responsible for the process, coaching the team, resolving impediments and guarding team from external interference. 
**Scrum Master doesn't have to be technical person.**

Many people (including me) claim that having significant technical expertise is definitely helpful in Scrum Master role and such Scrum Master tend to be much more effective. However having SM that is technical is not Scrum requirement.

## How this applies to you

**If your SM is strong technical person** that is naturally seen by Team as someone that can provide valuable feedback regarding code quality, design and architecture **I don't see reason why SM couldn't take on XP Coach this role** as long as he/she has enough time to keep up with both roles.

## Don't overload your SM

**If you decide to give SM additional role**, please be cautious. **Don't overload your SM** with other work than being SM. You need him/her to be focused on resolving impediments, inspecting and adapting process. This is crucial at this role and as i**t's hard to tangibly quantify SM work** it tends to be diminished when SM has more tangible work on his/her plate. You don't want this to happen.

> The same problem with Tracker. Who should be the conscience of team?
>   Scrum Master or it's better to appoint this to another person?

On the contrary to XP Coach, this one is in my opinion no-brainer. Scrum Master should be doing it.